# Read remote VSTS Build id dynamically from TFS 2015

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

We have a scenario in which :

TFS 2015 users commits the checkin's with CI, as part of CI build we run GIT commands which will sync current TFS 2015 repo to VSTS GIT Repo.

Below is the code (Sync part)

Right after it sync's the code in VSTS , It triggers a CI build in VSTS. (For that particular repo) . say eg: Build number is **Testbuild_0.1.8**

The requirement is to read the VSTS build status dynamically, and update the status in TFS 2015. I have come up with a script (look below) which get status of Build and display (but I have to send a hardcoded value, is there a way where I can dynamically read ?

Code 1 :

```
<pre> <code> git remote add vsts https://Personal%20Access%20Token:$PATToken@test.visualstudio.com/$GITProject/_git/$GITRepo 2>&1|Write-Host
    git checkout ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME}
    git reset --hard origin/master
    git push vsts ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME}
</pre> </code>
```

Code 2 :

I have to read the value Build ID or Build number dynamically and pass the value to get build status. Below [string]$buildNumber = "Testbuild_0.1.8" (marked bold) should be read dynamically ?

```
<pre> <code >

[CmdletBinding()]
Param(

   [string] $TFSURL = "https://remotevsts.visualstudio.com",
   [string] $TeamProject = "Test TP",
   **[string]$buildNumber = "Testbuild_0.1.8",**
   [string]$user = "test@live.com",
   [string]$token = "tokenid"
)

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$uri = "$TFSURL/$TeamProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&buildNumber=$($buildNumber)"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
if ($result.count -eq 0)
{
     throw "Unable to locate Build ID for Build Number $($buildNumber)"
}
$buildId = $result.value[0].id
Write-Host "$buildId"
$uri = "https://remotevsts.visualstudio.com/Test TP/_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)?api-version=2.0"
$responseFromGet = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)}
$status = $responseFromGet.status
Write-Host "$status"
while($status -ne "completed"){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    $responseFromGet = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64Authinfo)}
    $status = $responseFromGet.status
    Write-Host "Status: " + $status
}
if ($responseFromGet.result -eq "succeeded")
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Done"
}
 else 
 {
  Write-Error "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error testing if demo site is up"
    exit 1
}


</pre> </code>
```

Comment: To read VSTS build id from TFS2015 CI build, how do you make sure TFS build and VSTS build are both running at the same time? Can you show the detail workflow here. In most case, if VSTS build is triggered by the CI build from TFS2015, we can not control TFS build is running after the triggered VSTS build finished.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`List` api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to query recent builds (you can already scope the build with the parameters you know) and [then use the SourceBranch/SourceVersion to match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1#build) against the git ref that you have to find the correct build.

Alternatively don't set CI on the VSTS build and queue the build from TFS using the Build/Queue api. That way you know the exact build ID at queue time.